# Why am I getting SQLException: database is locked on my JDBC SQLite database?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have a single-threaded application that uses 3 SQLite databases in 3 different files on the local file system.

I have created a `DbAdapter` helper class that opens the connection to the SQLite database file. In this class I have an `open` method that creates the connection, and a `close` method that releases everything.

The 3 databases are accessed from a class that derives `DbAdapter`.

In my program every database access look like this:

```
MyDbAdapter DB = new MyDBAdapter();
int stuff = DB.getStuff(); // queries the database
DB.close();
// now do something with `stuff`
```

I have logged to `stdout` all calls to `DbAdapter.open` and `DbAdapter.close`. Everytime there's an `open()`, a `close()` follows close by.
I also take the care to close all my `Statement`s (which will cause the associated `ResultSet`s to be closed aswell).

So I guess that my database accesses are clean because I'm trying to get them as short as possible, and I release all the resources as soon as I no longer need them.

Yet, I'm still getting a `java.sql.SQLException: database is locked`.

Is there anything that I'm not doing properly? I know I haven't shown any code, but I'd have to post a LOT of code and it won't be relevant. I'm just asking if I'm using the best practises here, because I think I do and I'm still getting exceptions.

This is with Java 1.6, Xerial.org's sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2 driver, on Mac OS 10.6 x64

Comment: May be an old application process is running still? Is this still coming after a restart? Because as far as I know it's one process per embedded db not one thread....

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: database locked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578623/java-sql-sqlexception-database-locked)

Comment: @Thihara: I've `kill -9`'d all the java processes, still

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman: I've read this, but this hasn't helped me. My DB is closed, my `Statement`s are closed, my `ResultSet`s are closed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that I had strange Java processes that I couldn't kill. I ran:

```
ps aux | grep java | grep -v grep | awk '{print$2}' | xargs sudo kill -9
```

But those processes were still here (with same PID).

I rebooted, and the problem doesn't appear anymore. This doesn't make sense because I was able to make a lot of DB calls without any crash, there was just one single call that caused the exception. I don't understand at ALL what happened, but I'm no longer having this issue.

Any ***real*** answer welcome.

Comment: Told you :-P I think there were some rogue processes left over from some old runs. This has happened to me a few times as well. But that was in GUI applications where I've forgotten to set the EXIT_ON_CLOSE app to the main JFrame. As for the reason I'm not a linux guru. May be you will have better luck at SuperUser.

Comment: Yep you were right. I didn't think they were impacting my application because the executable was just `(java)` and not `/path/to/java/executable -arg1 -arg2 ...`. And that's Mac OS though, not linux! Unix ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem resulted from trying to update the database from Java, while having it open in SQLite Database Browser (which it seems, held a lock on the db).

Answer (score -1):

quoting from topic [java.sql.SQLException: database locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578623/java-sql-sqlexception-database-locked)

'Reading an SQLite database sets the locking state to Shared. Multiple readers can be active at the same time.

Writing to an SQLite database sets the locking state to Exclusive. No other processes can be active at that time.

You can find a detailed explanation on http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html'

I think this is your problem

Comment: How can this be my problem? Indeed, the connection to the DB is closed as soon as I don't need it anymore, and there cannot be concurrent accesses because my application is single-threaded.