# SQLite - Database is locked in Java

Tags: java, sqlite, database-locking

In a first method, I create the database, if not exists :

```
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

    Connection connection = null;
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + Gdx.files.internal("mjvsworld.db"));

    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GLOBAL(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" +
            " AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, MAXPUNTUATION INTEGER)");

    if (statement != null) statement.close();
    if (connection != null) connection.close();
```

In a second method, in other way (I do the same, changin' the update query), I try to read if some row in table was inserted, of If table was created now, insert it :

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO GLOBAL (ID, NAME, MAXPUNTUATION) VALUES "
                +"(1, 'Elvis', "+maxpoints+")");
```

In another call, after in the project, I try to update only one row (ID=1), and **in this one, gives me error **:

```
statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE GLOBAL set MAXPUNTUATION = "+puntos+" AND NAME = '"+name+"' where ID=1;");
```

´

**ERROR CODE : **

```
java.sql.SQLException: database is locked
at org.sqlite.NativeDB.throwex(NativeDB.java:210)
at org.sqlite.NativeDB._exec(Native Method)
at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeUpdate(Stmt.java:152)
at pack.util.DbConnection.actualizarMaxPuntuacion(DbConnection.java:94)
at pack.maingame.Platform.finalizarJuego(Platform.java:1060)
at pack.maingame.Platform.configurarDeteccionesJugador1(Platform.java:686)
at pack.maingame.Platform.render(Platform.java:443)
at pack.visual.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:51)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:208)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:115)


DbConnection.java:94 `equals to last executeUpdate I post.`
```

I need help with this. Thanks. (I don't use commit, I tried to use it and gives me error too)

Comment: Are you sure that after each execute statement you closed the connection? Also please check if other process (PIDs) are using the thread

Comment: I close every update , yes, I didn't understand the second thing u said

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134774/why-am-i-getting-sqlexception-database-is-locked-on-my-jdbc-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite used to throw such error while it is already open using any app like SQLite browser and we are using the same file in the code. So, close the database before running your code.